# Creating a variable inside of a for loop

Tags: python

I'm using python for creating a Dungeons and Dragons Character Creator, and am currently programming the weapons. I've recreated some code that has failed to work in previous similar environments, and I was wondering about a way for it to work without needing an if statement for each individual variable, so that editing for additional properties and items might be available.

The goal is to create an Weapon(Object) that has only the Properties(variables) associated with it.

Current Code:

```
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, finesse, light, thrown, two_handed, versatile):
        property_list = [finesse, light, thrown, two_handed, versatile]
        for prop in property_list:
            if prop != 0:
                self.prop = prop

dagger = Weapon('finesse', 'light', 'thrown', 0, 0)
```

Currently the variable wouldn't be created for the weapon; thus

```
dagger.finesse
```

Does not exist. Ideally `'finesse'` would be stored in the variable `dagger.finesse`, while the variable `dagger.two_handed` would not be created by the code.

I'm probably overlooking something simple, and there might be duplicate questions, but I can't find a similar question with the answer I'm looking for.

Thank you to all who reply

## Edits

Thank you to @WKPlus for some formatting assistance; I'm new to the stackoverflow website

I've realized thanks to @abarnert that the better way to do this is to have the porperties listed in a variable and to check that variable later in the code for the property, like so

```
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, finesse, light, thrown, two_handed, versatile):
        property_list = [finesse, light, thrown, two_handed, versatile]
        self.properties = []
        for prop in property_list:
            if prop != 0:
                self.properties.append(prop)
```

However, I'm still interested in seeing how my original question might be answered, as it could still be useful to run something like my original without the exclusion statement.

Comment: Why do you want `Weapon.finesse` to be the string `'finesse'` or nonexistent? Wouldn't it be better to have it be, say, a bool that's true for daggers and false for clubs?

Comment: Think about how you're going to use this. Do you want to to `try: player.weapon.finesse except AttributeError:` all over the code?

Comment: Ideally, there would be multiple subclasses of `Weapon`.

Comment: It might be better if finesse was a bool; however, I am wanting to be able to create a character sheet where the player can see that the dagger he/she is using has the finesse property, and it would be simple to print `dagger.finesse` in the slot. Maybe not the best way, but my current idea for how to do it.

Comment: @Bristles: So how exactly is that code going to work? It's not going to be "simple" to print `player.weapon.finesse` if that raises an `AttributeError` if the weapon doesn't have that attribute.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I currently have multiple weapon classes in the code, but it seemed difficult to ask

Comment: @abarnert There would probably need to be a secondary attribute for the weapon suchas `dagger.properties` which would be a list of the properties.

Comment: @abarnert I'm an idiot. I could just append the properties to a variable `dagger.properties` and check that for the values as needed.

Comment: @Bristles I think that makes sense. It separates the weapon properties from the "Weapon class" attributes. You can just check for presence of a particular property (eg `if 'thrown' in weapon.properties:`), or print out the whole list if needed.

Comment: @Bristles: Yes, that makes sense. Just make `properties` be a `list` or `set` of strings, and then everything is a lot easier.

Comment: @Bristles Using dictionaries or the ["builder pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) is fun here :) If you want it simple, just make properties a `dictionary` (or a set, if you don't need the properties to map to any value), and then you'll have strings mapping to values of your choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, finesse=False, light=False, thrown=False, two_handed=False,
                 versatile=False):
        props = locals()
        props.pop('self')
        for prop, value in props.items():
            if value:
                setattr(self, prop, value)
```

Now:

```
dagger = Weapon('finesse', 'light', 'thrown', 0, 0)
```

or:

```
dagger = Weapon('finesse', 'light', 'thrown')
```

1. I use default arguments that I set to `False`. So if you do not provide them
   they are `False`.
2. `locals()` gives you a dictionary of all local variables defined so far.
   Here, these are the arguments to `__init__()`.
   Since you don't want `self.self`, use `props.pop('self')` to remove it.
3. The `self.prop = prop does` not work.

   For example, if you a class `A` and a variable `x`:

   ```
   class A(object):
       pass
   x = 1
   ```

   This:

   ```
   for obj in [x]:
       A.obj = obj
   ```

   gives an attribute `obj`

   ```
   >>> A.obj
   1
   ```

   where this:

   ```
   setattr(A, 'x', x)
   ```

   gives you an attribute `x`:

   ```
   >>> A.x
   1
   ```

   You need `setattr(self, name, value)` to set an attribute programmatically.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `**kwargs` and `setattr`:

```
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        property_list = ['finesse', 'light', 'thrown', 'two_handed', 'versatile']
        for prop in property_list:
            setattr(self, prop, kwargs.get(prop, False))

dagger = Weapon(finesse=True, light=True, thrown=True)
```

This will look for any of the properties in `property_list` in the passed arguments and set that attribute on `self`. If the property isn't found, it gets set to `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Other than using `setattr` to set attribute, your also can parse your args into a dict and update the `__dict__` attribute with it:

```
class Weapon:
    def __init__(self, finesse, light, thrown, two_handed, versatile):
        property_list = ['finesse', 'light', 'thrown', 'two_handed', 'versatile']
        property_values = dict([(name,eval(name)) for name in property_list])
        self.__dict__.update(property_values)

dagger = Weapon('finesse', 'light', 'thrown', 0, 0)
print dagger.finesse
```